# How to delete all generated binary files in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, versioning, binaryfiles, temporary-files

I am not sure if the subject description is correct but basically this is what I want to achieve:

I want to have a way to delete all binary files such as .exe, .dll to be deleted at a single click. Perhaps there are plugins available that will let me do the same, but just wondering if something like that exists already.

The reason I want to do this is to make sure that all such temporary created files, which aren't usually needed for versioning a project, are deleted prior to making any commit to the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the Build menu, Click `Clean Solution.`

Or, right click on the solution and Click `Clean Solution`

Have a look at

[What does "Clean Solution" under Build Menu in Visual Studio do ?](http://geeks-squad.blogspot.com/2008/07/what-does-clean-solution-under-build.html)

[How to: Prepare and Manage Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/5tdasz7h%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Will clean solution delete the EXE file?

Comment: Choose Clean Solution to **delete any intermediate and output files**, so Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Gunner: Should do, though I think it leaves the .suo and some other file that shouldn't be checked in either (since they're user/machine specific). Regarding your question, I do it the other way around and use a filter to make sure that it ignores certain kinds of files during commits.

Comment: @ho1: I am also aware of setting filters, but at some situations, that is not possible. Let's say the SVN client doesn't support ignore(only an example). That is why I was wondering if such a feature implicitly existed with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: It doesn't clean the Setup files created inside the Release or Debug folder of Setup Project. However, the EXE files inside actual project file gets deleted. Is that intentional not the delete Setup project EXE files, perhaps to allow versioning of those files.

Answer (score 2):

well, may be you can do it the manual way .  create a batch file called for example Clean.bat

and put in it:

```
del yoursolutionfolder *.pdb *.exe *.obj /s
```

and call it whenever you want to clean up the solution.

Comment: Thats one way to do it :). This was the only way in the tough old days of console mode development.